# Run create-react-app in production mode in Docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, create-react-app

I'm trying to run a create-react-app project in production mode inside a docker container. I have the following Dockerfile.

```
FROM node:10

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
RUN npm install serve
RUN yarn global add serve

# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

CMD serve -s build
```

Each time I run this container, I get `"INFO: Accepting connections at http://localhost:5000"` but the nothing shows on port 5000. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: it should `0.0.0.0:5000` and did you publish port?

Comment: I'm not seeing build command in here, "npm run build" need to be done first.

Comment: @Adiii what do you mean? The EXPOSE 5000 is in the dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

You are running a webserver inside your container. It listens on a port. You need to know the port and then publish it.

For example, you discovered that your webserver listens on port 5000. Then you can publish the port by using command-line argument `docker run -p 5000:5000`

`EXPOSE` doesn't publish the port, it merely records some meta information inside the container and this information can be used by `docker run -P`. The capital `'P'` means: do publish all exposed ports. This is rarely done so `EXPOSE` is used more like a hint for users of your `DOCKERFILE` regarding the `docker run -p XXXX:YYYY` port publishing you expect them to do.